# Laravel 404 error - views not found in layout sub folder

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-blade

I have set up a new Laravel project. However, after creating a new Blade layout file and adding it to a subfolder in /resources/views/layouts/custom, I keep getting a 404 error view not found. Note that the layout is referenced using the following.

```
@extends('layouts.custom.template')
```

However, moving the blade file from the custom folder to layouts and updating the `@extends` to `@extends('layouts. template')` works fine. I can't create and access any subfolder in views for some reason. Not sure if this is a Laravel issue or an Apache issue.

Comment: try clearing views cache files by running the command ``php artisan view:clear`` and test

Comment: Stack Trace returns:  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137

Comment: Omi Shah, i have tried clearing, cache, views and route - no luck

Comment: Post the complete stack trace log also consider checking the views sub directories file permisison

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/Rmrn0lNm#F58

Comment: @OMiShah - lol .. you where right it was a permission problem, the webserver was blocked from accessing the sub folder.. cant believe i missed that.. thanks for help

Comment: it happens, we learn and then share from our past experiences ;)